# Sending HTTP Request to Node JS from External Network

Tags: node.js, http, ip

I am trying to send the simplest NodeJS response to HTTP requests as below.
I used several listen parameters as below suggested by other posts. While the response works for computers on the same network, when I try sending request from networks outside (such as my mobile connected to cellular data), there is no response. Am I missing any sort of configuration which blocks external requests? I tried both internal and external IPs (that prints from the codes below) but no lock.
I am in oz using TPG internet, Belkin N300 router and Windows 10 (with only Windows defender).

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Amir Server\n');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");

console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');

'use strict';
var getIP = require('external-ip')();

getIP(function (err, ip) {
    if (err) {
        // every service in the list has failed 
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(ip);
});


var os = require('os');

var interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
var addresses = [];
for (var k in interfaces) {
    for (var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
        var address = interfaces[k][k2];
        if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
            addresses.push(address.address);
        }
    }
}

console.log(addresses);
```

Comment: Does the code represent the contents of a single file?

Comment: No file. it is just a string.

Comment: I'm guessing that the host computer that your server is running on is not accessible from the outside world of the internet (which would be the typical case for any home network).  It is probably blocked by a firewall.  In addition, you would have to make sure that some public IP address is actually routed to the host computer that your server is running on . The usual solution is to either run your server on a publicly hosted server (at some sort of hosting provider) or to set up port forwarding so your firewall will forward requests to a specific port through the firewall and to your server.

Comment: I get the same public IP address for all devices connected to my home internet. I assume the request would go through the router and dismissed, is this right?